# Watson Assistant Slots: how to allow the user to re-enter data using non-dictionary entities?

Tags: websphere, ibm-watson, entities, watson-assistant, slots

I want to capture the following input from the user and am using these entities:

- First and last names: use sys-person (I extract first and last names later using a cloud action).
- Email address: use pattern entity, name @contactEmail and value "email" pattern \b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+.)+[A-Za-z]{2,}\b
- Mobile Number: use pattern entity, name @contactPhone and value "mobileNumber" pattern ^[1-9][0-9]{7}[0-9]+$

**Slots**

I created a node with slots:

[image: Slots]

The setup is as follows:

Check for:

- Check for: @sys-person.literal  Save it as $person   If not present: Type your name
- Check for: @contactEmail.literal  Save it as $email  If not present: Type your email
- Check for: @contactPhone.literal  Save it as $contactPhone  If not present: Type your mobile.

This all works perfectly and I get the name, email address and Phone number.

**The Challenge**
But I want the user to be able to confirm that the details are correct.
So I have an intent called #response_yes which is activated by things like "yes", "yep", etc.

And I have a fourth slot that checks for #response_yes.

- Check for #response_yes, store the value in $confirmed, if not present ask "Got $person, $contactEmail, $contactPhone is that correct?"

[image: Confirmation]

If #response_yes is not found, then it displays the values already typed and asks if they are correct and waits for user input.

After the user has responded, then if the #reponse_yes intent is still not found, then:

[image: Start again]

Respond with, "Let's start again".
Also, we need to clear the values already typed:

[image: Clear the values]

**Here's where it goes wrong**
When I try the chatbot, the node collects the input correctly and displays the values correctly and asks if they are correct.  I type "no", the #response_no intent is correctly divined and I would expect the prompt for the first slot to show again, but it doesn't.

[image: The problem]

No matter what I type at that point, the assistant bypasses the top three slots and drops to the fourth one again.  It's as if I need to clear the entities, not the variables.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I make the top slot work again?!

Answer (score 0):

Aaaaargh.

For anyone who's interested, I simply didn't reset the values to null.

I guess I assumed that leaving the value blank was the same as null.  Not so.  Once I did this, the system worked perfectly:

[image: Set the values to null!]